# Is the set $\{1,2\}$ is contained in another set, does it count as one element of that set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I had $\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}$, would the $\{1,2\}$ inside the set count as one element?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, but if I had $\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$, $3$ would not be an element. ($\{3,4\}$ _would_, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would. The set $\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}$ has three elements: $1,2$ and $\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed.

An easy way would be to write $a=\{1,2\}$, then your set is $\{1,2,a\}$. In that form you can easily see that $a$ is an element of the set.